# override level of subcategory in log4j configuration

Tags: java, log4j, auditing

There is some auditing in my application. Every audit event has it's own log4j category with name that is prefixed by same string.

EG:
general auditing category name: com.company.audit

web login category name: com.company.audit.web.login
create something: com.company.audit.api.create
etc..

some of the categories should be logged by default, but some not =>

```
<category name="com.compamy.audit" additivity="true">
    <priority value="INFO"/>
</category>

<category name="com.company.audit.web.login" additivity="true">
  <priority value="DEBUG">
</category>
```

As default is INFO second category shouldn't be logged. At least I thought it but it doesn't work. Any help how to override logging level on 'sub-category'.

NOTE: I don't have much possibility to change a naming scheme as a whole

ADDED:

here is configuration of appender:

```
<appender class="org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender" name="Company_AUDIT">

<param name="File" value="${jboss.server.log.dir}/company_audit.log"/>

<param value="10000KB" name="MaxFileSize"/>

<param value="10" name="MaxBackupIndex"/>

<layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
    <param name="ConversionPattern" value="foo"/>
</layout>

</appender>
```

Comment: What level is the second category logged at?  Is it logged at INFO or at DEBUG?  The problem could be with your appender configuration.

Comment: I realized later that it's logged twice...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration means: for category `com.company.audit`, log all messages of level `INFO` or higher. For `com.company.audit.web.login`, log all messages of level `DEBUG` or higher. So all the messages of the second category are logged, which is what you asked for.

What you really want is to select whether the second category is displayed or not. I can think of two approaches to do that:

1. in your code, use the convention that all messages in `com.company.audit` will be logged at level `INFO`, and all messages in `com.company.audit.web.login` will be logged at level `DEBUG`. In your configuration, you only need to set the level of the main category:

   - `DEBUG`: display all messages
   - `INFO`: don't display "optional" messages (i.e. those of the subcategory)
2. In the configuration, put `com.company.audit.web.login` to level `OFF` when you want to disable its messages. When you want to activate it, just comment the line (it will inherit the configuration from the main category).

I prefer the second option, because you can keep using the level for message gravity (what it is originally meant for).

Comment: I thought it should work exactly as you wrote. But it looks like log4j match both categories a it does logging for both of them = if com.company.audit is INFO it logs once and then it logs also as com.company.audit.web.login (if it's not OFF)